# Как верно передать "класс" в метод?

Tags: c#, методы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть два класса; (Star,Circle)
Есть ли возможность передать данный класс в метод с вызовом его конструктора.

Сейчас использую дженереки, но конструктор не работает

Пример:

```
public static T getObj<T>( int size, int i) where T : new()
{
   return _objs[i] = new T(new Point(rnd.Next(0, 800), i * 20), new Point(5 - i, 15 - i), new Size(size, size));
}
```

Сам вызов:

```
getObj<Star>(3, i)
```

Ошибка: CS0417  'T": при создании экземпляра типа переменной не удается задать аргументы

как верно передать класс в метод заместо "new T"?

Comment: а у этих ваших классов конструкторы одинаковые?

Comment: Да, public Star(Point pos, Point dir, Size size) : base(pos, dir, size) {}

Comment: ну тогда `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), /*ваши параметры*/)` вам в помощь

Comment: А эти ваши Star и Circle неизменяемые что ли? Нельзя вместо параметров конструктора действовать через свойства?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

То, в каком виде пытаетесь это сделать Вы, сделать не получится.
 Вы не можете наложить ограничение на `T`, чтобы у него обязательно был конструктор с указанными Вами типами параметров.

```
where T : new()
```

Данное [ограничение new](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) работает следующим образом:

> Оно указывает, что аргумент любого переданного типа
>   должен иметь открытый конструктор без
>   параметров.

Как видите, нам это не подходит. Точнее, не совсем.
Давайте рассмотрим несколько вариантов решения Вашей проблемы

---

### #0. Наследование

Раз Вы пытаетесь объединить объекты, значит, они явно наделены общей логикой. А общую логику в ООП принято выносить в [абстракции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Давайте так и поступим!

Я не знаю деталей реализации Вашей программы, но, судя по названиям, Вы работаете с некими фигурами. Запишем все это дело так:

```
// Абстрактный родительский класс
public abstract class Shape
{
    // Свойства, которые будут у всех его потомков
    public Point A { get; set; }
    public Point B { get; set; }
    public Size C { get; set; }

    // Публичные инициализаторы
    public Shape() { }
    // Тот инициализатор, что Вы пытаетесь использовать
    public Shape(Point A, Point B, Size C)
    {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        this.C = C;
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    // Реализовываем нужные инициализаторы
    public Circle() { }
    public Circle(Point A, Point B, Size C) : base(A, B, C)
    {
        // SOMETHING
    }
}

public class Star : Shape
{
    // Реализовываем нужные инициализаторы
    public Star() { }
    public Star(Point A, Point B, Size C) : base(A, B, C)
    {
        // SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Теперь же давайте изменим Ваш метод:

```
// Добавим ограничение, что T может являться только потомком Shape
public static T GetShape<T>(Point A, Point B, Size C) where T : Shape, new()
{
    // Используем инициализатор по умолчанию, установив все свойства вручную
    T obj = new T
    {
        A = A,
        B = B,
        C = C
    };

    return obj;
}
```

Если же Вам нужно не просто установить значения свойств и в инициализатор спрятана какая-то хитрая логика, то метод можно переписать так:

```
// Добавим ограничение, что T может являться только потомком Shape
public static T GetShape<T>(Point A, Point B, Size C) where T : Shape
{
    // Получим тип T
    Type type = typeof(T);

    // Вручную сопоставим типы
    if (type == typeof(Star))
        // Преобразуем Star к базовому классу, а после - к T, 
        // который, как указано в ограничении, является Shape
        return (T)(Shape)new Star(A, B, C);
    else
        if (type == typeof(Circle))
            // Преобразуем Circle к базовому классу, а после - к T, 
            // который, как указано в ограничении, является Shape
            return (T)(Shape)new Circle(A, B, C);

    // Если тип не опознан - выбросим ошибку 
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Или же можно использовать [сопоставление шаблонов из C# 7.0+](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) (данный вариант представлен больше для демонстрации указанных возможностей языка, чем для использования в реальных проектах):

```
// Добавим ограничение, что T может являться только потомком Shape
public static T GetShape<T>(Point A, Point B, Size C) where T : Shape, new()
{
    // Инициализатор по умолчанию
    // Этот метод подразумевает создание объекта дважды,
    // что не очень логически верно. Не делайте  так)
    T obj = new T();

    // Используем паттерны сопоставления
    switch (obj)
    {
        case Star star:
            star = new Star(A, B, C);
            obj = (T)(Shape)star;
            break;
        case Circle circle:
            circle = new Circle(A, B, C);
            obj = (T)(Shape)circle;
            break;
        default:
            // Тип не распознан
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

---

### #1. Явное обращение к рефлексии

То, что Вы хотите, можно реализовать и с помощью нашей дорогой и любимой [рефлексии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) (однако сразу предупреждаю, что это медленнее вышеописанного подхода. Не очень заметно на малых выборках, но все же именно поэтому рекомендуется использовать варианты выше)
От слов к делу:

```
public static T GetShape<T>(Point A, Point B, Size C)
{
    // Получим тип T
    Type type = typeof(T);

    // Получаем открытый конструктор, в который надо передать два объекта типа Point и один типа Size
    ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Point), typeof(Point), typeof(Size) });
    if (constructor != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Вызовем конструктор с указанными параметрами
            object result = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { A, B, C });

            // Если все прошло удачно, то приведем результат к указанному типу и вернем
            if (result != null)
                return (T)result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Ошибочка вышла, обработайте ее!
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    // У нас ничего не вышло, значит, тип не соответсвует заданным условиям
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Метод можно порядком ужать. Я все расписываю, чтобы Вам было удобнее и понятнее читать)

Как ужать? Таким образом, используя [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static T GetShape<T>(Point A, Point B, Size C)
{
    try
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), A, B, C);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Обработайте ошибку. Ее появление означает, 
        // что у заданного типа нет нужного конструктора 
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Данный метод делает ровно то, что и предыдущий (описанный для Вашего лучшего понимания подноготной), только встроенными возможностями

С помощью рефлексии можно реализовать метод безо всякого наследования и сопоставления типов, так что метод динамически расширяем (то есть если Вы добавите еще 10 классов, реализующих указанный конструктор, Вам не придется менять данный метод для их создания, в отличие от описанных выше с помощью наследования)

---

### UPD:

Спасибо [@PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash) за поправку!

Итак, согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
T obj = new T();
```

также использует рефлексию для создания объекта.
То есть данное выражение эквивалентно следующему:

```
T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам разобраться в вопросе и решил Вашу проблему! 
Удачи в Ваших начинаниях!

Comment: *Такой подход, пожалуй, будет самым правильным.* — а зачем объект по два раза создавать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я не про метод, а про подход с наследованием целиком) Так-то да, создавать объект дважды, как в последнем варианте, может быть немного лишним (главное, чтобы пустой инициализатор ничего не делал), просто уж больно я люблю фишечки C# 7+, так что не мог не привести пример)

Comment: Товарищи, хоть говорите, за что минус ставите хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov чаще всего не говорят, за что минус :( Лично мне не по душе именование в одну букву, но я плюсанул :D

Comment: @DenisBubnov да так всегда хД Да именовать так и неправильно и, что самое важное, противоречит правилам хорошего тона: «Называйте переменные короткими, но понятными и самодокументируемыми именами». Я же не знаю деталей реализации ТС, верно? Так что как же я могу дать им вменяемые названия? :D Тут главное принцип

Comment: Глушить исключения и возвращать null - не лучшая идея. В релизной сборке этот код будет просто молча возвращать null,  что скорее всего будет стоить какому-нибудь разработчику пару часов жизни на отладку. И создание объекта дважды (да еще и через неяавный reflection, new T()) - ради фишечек, и со свичем по типам, обозначенный как "самый правильный" - это очень странно :(

Comment: @PashaPash ответ ведь не про это) Я вообще добавил блоки исключений **только** ради того, чтобы показать, что это дело может кидать исключения, которые надо обработать, а как обрабатывать - дело уже за ТС (вы часто видеть в релизных сборках Debug.WritiLine :)?). Так-то я с Вами более чем согласен. А по поводу `самый правильный` - я уже пояснил выше, что правилен не последний метод(!), а полностью нулевой пункт, стремящийся к решению задачи без рефлексии!

Comment: @PashaPash хм, интересный вопрос у меня в голове появился: а что будет сильнее тормозить исполнение: ветвление (ошибки предсказателя переходов) или же рефлексия. С увеличением ветвления ошибки предсказателя будут происходить чаще, а вот время исполнения рефлексии в общем-то стабильно. Так что, полагаю, где-то есть разумная граница, когда стоит отказаться от ветвления в пользу рефлексии. В общем, это уже меня в лирику понесло. А так - Вы правы, я подредактирую ответ, ибо его местами не так интерпретируют)

Comment: @PashaPash обновил ответ, чтобы больше никто не смущался)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov у вас в нулевом пункте, в вариантах с наследованием и со switch используется рефлексия - 'new T()' в генерик методах компилируется в Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)), а не в вызов конструктора :(

Comment: @PashaPash ого. Спасибо Вам большое, до этого не знал) Сейчас добавлю в ответ